# .htaccess remove php extension AND redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I know how to redirect pages, but I was wondering how I could remove the .php extension as well as redirect?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./load.php?code=$1
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Can you provide an example of the URL you are trying to use and where it should redirect to?  I'm unclear on what you mean by 'remove the .php extension as well as redirect'.  Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

I saw a thread here discuss the same issue. http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4148146.htm

You can use this answer in that topic of [jDMorgan](http://www.webmasterworld.com/profilev4.cgi?action=view&member=jdMorgan) It will check if the request is not assets files and if it exist extension php in the url, they will redirect and remove .php

```
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|zip)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [b]/$1[/b].php [b][L][/b]
```